# ASP.NET Azure Blob Geographically Redundant Storage - How to use?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have been searching for an answer on MS, SE and Google and cannot find it.  I want to use the GRS option for Azure Storage (Cloud Block Blobs) but I cannot figure out how to properly do that.

I created my storage object in Azure and chose the GRS option.

I get that I have a primary and secondary connection string and know how to get that from the Azure portal.

What I do not know, in ASP.NET 4.0, is how to set both connection strings in the CloudBlockClient and gracefully handle the primary storage being unavailable.
--What exception is thrown and where, when primary is unavailable?  Is this thrown when I create the client, or when I try to get a blob reference?
-- How do I then use the secondary?

Do I have to just test for any old exception and then try using the secondary connection string in a new CloudBlockClient if the primary does not work?  Or is there anything in the API for this.  I would think there would be but I cannot find it.

None of the "How to use Azure Storage" tutorials I have seen go into this.  Most of the documentation seems to date from before mid-2014 when this feature became generally available.

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/12/04/introducing-read-access-geo-replicated-storage-ra-grs-for-windows-azure-storage.aspx) should help you. In short if you want to read from both primary and secondary you want to enable RA-GRS - essentially read access from the secondary. If you are using out storage client libraries you can also enable a retry policy that will first try to read from a primary and then from the secondary if the first read fails.

Comment: This helps for sure - the code at the bottom helps.  The current documentation online for the storage library doesn't really go into this.